# Diffeomorphism of sorted vectors and a box

Tags: real-analysis, change-of-variable, diffeomorphism

Let $A = \left\{ a \in \mathbb R^n \;\middle|\; a_1 \geq \cdots \geq a_n \geq 0 \right\}$ be the set of sorted non-negative vectors in $\mathbb R^n$. I'm looking for a diffeomorphism $\varphi : A \to B$, where $B$ is a "box" in $\mathbb R^n$. By a box, I mean a set of the form $B = \prod_{i=1}^n I_i$, where $I_i$ is an interval or ray in $\mathbb R$. (Extra points if $B = \mathbb R^n$.)

Comment: I have no special experience with diffeomorphisms, but wouldn't $B=[0,\infty)^n$ and $\phi((a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)) = (a_1-a_2,a_2-a_3,\ldots,a_{n-1}-a_n,a_n)$ work? It is certainly a bijection and both $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}((b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n)) = (\sum_{i=1}^n b_i, \sum_{i=2}^n b_i,\ldots,b_{n-1}+b_n,b_n)$ seem to me differentiable.

Comment: Indeed it is! That (and taking logs to get $B = \mathbb R^n$) is actually what I had in mind

Comment: I don't think you can get $B=\mathbb{R}^n$, because you have nothing to map the $0$ to. In other words, I *think* that $[0,\infty)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are in fact *not* diffeomorph. Actually, they are not homeomorph, so AFAIK they can't be diffeomorph.

Comment: You're right, I was "cheating" and requiring $a_n > 0$